# CakePHP - generating SQL update statement without apostrophes

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to call updateAll function on Model and update text column but CakePHP doesn't add apostrophes to SQL command.

Is there any special setting to make it active? Is it necessary to do sanitization manually?

I'm using CakePHP 2.3 and MySQL 5.1

CakePHP

```
$this->User->updateAll(
        array('User.about_me' => $about),
        array('User.id' => $id)             
);
```

SQL command

```
UPDATE `test`.`users` AS `User` 
SET `User`.`about_me` = Nunc posuere risus sed elit ornare malesuada.  
WHERE `User`.`id` = 8956954
```

Comment: Is your cakePhp code inside a Model?

Comment: No, code is in a User controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this one is a little unexpected, but if you open cookbook and read about `updateAll`, it is clearly stated, that "Literal values should be quoted manually using `DboSource::value()`". Or if you don't use user input, you can quote it yourself like: `array('User.state' => "'active'")`

More [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions)